# Nginx Vs Apache to solve load isseu on website

Tags: mysql, apache, networking, operating-system, system

So Have a web application that has 10-12 pages with many POST/ GET DB Calls. We usually have a apache crash/other problem when site traffic results to 1000 or so (concurrent users) which is very small number, we have updated server with good RAM and resources. When our system admin guy do load testing on blitz and other custom script and is suggesting to move away from Apache. Some things does not make sense to me. Like Apache is not too bad to handle few thousand of concurrent users considering we have cloudflare for caching. Here is what he suggested:

replacement of Apache+mod_fcgi with Nginx+php-fpm which can make the server handle much more users, and then test it.
or
2. For testing: Need 10-20 servers to run a scenario from. Basically, what is needed is a more complex blitz.io analogue. create one server, which takes all those hours, then just clone it in the cloud and pay for about 1 hour of testing multiplied by the number of servers needed.

Once again there are many DB calls anf HT access. ALso what makes Nginx better than apache in this case?

Comment: he also added : Apache dies at about 200 requests per second. Well, maybe I can make it 300 if you want to keep this setup. But I can also make it at least 1000 if we can get rid of Apache.

Comment: Apache seems to reach the file descriptor limits (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/fd-limits.html). Most linux system by default only allows 1024 files being opened by a user. This is obviously not enough for a web server because each concurrent connection needs at least 1 file descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

[I would check this comparison first.](http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/Apache_vs_nginx) Basically, nginx is event based, so it's able to handle more requests concurrently. However, as the MySQL DB seems to be the choke point here, it's very possible that nginx wouldn't solve all your problems. Perhaps moving to a NoSQL kind of database, that's better at scaling horizontally, would help (if that's feasible).